# Input a char in struct using getche in C?

Tags: c

I have a problem with inputting a char in C. I want the user to input only `x` or `X`. If not, user has to input again. Moreover, I want to do it with a struct. This is my code:

```
typedef struct chu{
    char c;
};

int main(){
    chu input;
    char temp;
    do{
        printf("\nInput: ");
        temp=getche();
        if((temp!='x')||(temp!='X')) 
            printf("\nWrong input (only 'x' or 'X')");
        else
            input.c=temp;
    }while((temp!='x')||(temp!='X'));
}
```

When I input `x` or `X`, I shouldn't input again.

Answer (score 3):

Your if condition is wrong it should be:

```
if((temp!='x') && (temp!='X')) 
               ^  && if not both
```

I replaced `||` with `&&` (*because any one is accepted, so if temp not equals to both then condition wrong message should print*)

Second while condition should be:

```
while(!((temp =='x') || (temp=='X')));
      ^
```

as you says *When I input x or X, I shouldn't input again* So if `temp` is either `x` or `X` then `(temp =='x') || (temp=='X')` == `1` and because of `!` it gives `while(0)` and loop breaks

Additionally, your struct definition should be like:

```
typedef struct {
    char c;
}chu;
```

I corrected your code you can find [from here](http://codepad.org/hGXzLjit) and try on your machine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem rests with your condition:

```
} while((temp!='x')||(temp!='X'));
```

This means: Repeat while it's either unequal 'x' OR 'X'. (Which is always true, because it can only be one or the other.
Replace this with:

```
} while(temp != 'x' && temp != 'X');
```

Repeat while it's not either 'x' or 'X'.
The same problem is in your `if` further up (I seem to have overlooked this the first time around, my bad).

Your code may be reconstructed like this:

```
int main(){
    chu input;
    char temp;
    while(true) {
        printf("\nInput: ");
        temp=getche();
        if(temp != 'x' && temp != 'X') 
            printf("\nWrong input (only 'x' or 'X')");
        else {
            input.c=temp;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This code will loop forever (as indicated by `while(true)`), but as soon as you enter 'x' or 'X' it will set the variable to your struct and `break` free from your loop.

A little information about semantics:

Anything connected by OR (`||`) will stop being evaluated, as soon as the first condition returns `true`. At that moment, the entire construct will return `true`, no matter what.

On the contrary, anything you connect with AND (`&&`) will stop evaluating as soon as the first condition returns `false`, since it makes the entire construct `false` anyway.

To get back to your example, this is what your compiler does, assuming we input 'X'

```
if(temp != 'x') {      //Okay, it's not 'x'. Let's try the next one.
    if(temp != 'X') {  //Oh wait, it IS X. I can't stop yet!
        //Stop looping
    }                  //This will be executed
}
//Loop me!
```

And this is what it does with `&&`

```
if(temp == 'x') {      //Hmm...not 'x'.
    if(temp == 'X') {  //Oh wait! It IS 'X'.
        //Stop looping //This gets executed.
    }
}
//Loop me!
```

You may have noticed, that I changed `!=` to `==` here. I can do that, because of binary arithmetic. NOT (x OR X) equals (NOT x AND NOT X).

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan The way I understand it, he wants the program to stop once x || X is input, isn't that correct? However the way this program is set up, it will loop indefinitely, no matter what you input.

Comment: sorry for delayed response: can find why this is wrong `(temp != 'x' && temp != 'X');`  **HINT** try two times for temp = `X` and temp temp = `a`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan I'm afraid I can't follow. If you put `X` into `temp` the equation returns false and the loop breaks, if you put `a` it doesn't. (And you get printed the error message)